# PL/SQL BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER DOESNT STOP INSERT

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I tried to write a trigger which checks to make sure conditions are met before it allows a person to be booked on the passenger list. But when the condition is not met, I want to prohibit insertion into the passengerlist. My trigger fires but the insertion takes place no matter what. How can I resolve this? What I am doing wrong?

For Example,

```
INSERT INTO  passengerlist_my (flightID, personID, seatnumber)
    VALUES (1, 5, '43B');
```

The above insert statement executes when it doesn't meet the condition. Person with personID 5 is already booked., but when I run the insert statement, it still inserts

```
SET serveroutput ON
    /
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bookpersons
    BEFORE INSERT ON  passengerlist_my
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
       --declaration section
       checkflight number;
       bookedseats number;
       planecapacity number;
       chkpbooked number;

       FLIGHT_IS_FULL EXCEPTION;
       PERSON_IS_BOOKED EXCEPTION;
       querystr VARCHAR2(255) := 'INSERT INTO  passengerlist_my (flightID, personID, seatnumber)
                                    VALUES (:NEW.flightID, :NEW.personID, :NEW.seatnumber)';

    BEGIN
        --check IF FLIGHT exists
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO checkflight FROM FLIGHT WHERE flightID = :NEW.flightID;
        IF checkflight<1 THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2000, 'Flight doesnt Exist');
        END IF;   

        --check booked seats
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO bookedseats FROM  passengerlist WHERE flightID = :NEW.flightID;

        --check plane capacity
        SELECT NUMBEROFSEATS INTO planecapacity FROM PLANETYPE
        JOIN PLANE USING (PLANETYPEID)
        JOIN FLIGHT USING (PLANEID)
        WHERE flightID = :NEW.flightID;

        --check if person is already booked
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO chkpbooked 
        FROM PASSENGERLIST_MY 
        WHERE FLIGHTID = :NEW.flightID AND personID = :NEW.personID;
        IF chkpbooked>=1 THEN
            RAISE PERSON_IS_BOOKED;
        END IF;

        IF bookedseats>=planecapacity THEN
            RAISE FLIGHT_IS_FULL;
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO  passengerlist_my (flightID, personID, seatnumber)
        VALUES (:NEW.flightID, :NEW.personID, :NEW.seatnumber);
        COMMIT;


    EXCEPTION
        WHEN FLIGHT_IS_FULL THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This flight is FULL. Passenger cannot be booked!');
        WHEN PERSON_IS_BOOKED THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Person is already booked!');
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error Occured. Passenger cannot be booked!');
    END;
    /
```

Comment: Does it still give you the output line? I think if you use THROW or RAISERROR instead of RAISE it should work.

Comment: Yes it gives the proper output line saying "The person is already booked" , but still inserts into the table anyway

Comment: You are handling the exception and not re-raising it, so the insert is not prevented.  Also you do not need the INSERT and COMMIT in the trigger code.

Comment: There are constraints ofcourse, but I am not allowed to insert to or modify the table passengerlist. I created a copy of the table with which I am working with.  @Tony Andrews, I don't really understand your comment, could you please make it bit clearer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your exception handler is eating the exceptions instead of re-raising them. Try changing the exception handler to:

```
EXCEPTION
    WHEN FLIGHT_IS_FULL THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This flight is FULL. Passenger cannot be booked!');
      RAISE;

    WHEN PERSON_IS_BOOKED THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Person is already booked!');
      RAISE;

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error Occured. Passenger cannot be booked!');
      RAISE;
```

This will cause the exceptions to be re-raised to any existing handler in the invoking code, which should be smart enough to roll back the transaction.

Share and enjoy.